# Why do reversed list and original list on comparison result as equal although the item indices for a particular item are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am implementing this code:

```
a = input("Enter number")
list_a = list(a)
temp = list_a
list_a.reverse()
print(temp == list_a)
#input:513
#output:False
```

But instead of getting `False`, I am getting `True`. Why does **reversed list** and **original list** on comparison give `True`?

Comment: `lista` is not defined. You meant `list_a`, right?

Comment: `temp` and `list_a` are *two different references to the same list*